# program does not scans the number 149, and for any other number it returns 0

Tags: c

my program should be scanning a certain number (unsigned long int) and returns its odd 'turned on' indexes bits(from the binary representation of the number). but the program doesn't identify any numbers, and just returns 0, or ,does not respond at all to the number. what am i doing wrong ?

this is the fucntion:

```
int count_odd_bits(unsigned long int x) {

    int count = 0;
    while (x) {
        if ((x % 2 == 1) && (x & 1))
            count++;
        else
            x = x << 1;

    }
    return count;
}
```

this is the main function:

```
int main() {

    unsigned long int x;
    printf("\n enter a number: \n");
    scanf("%ul", &x);
    int count_odd_bits(unsigned long int x);
    printf("\n the result is:%d \n",count_odd_bits(x));

    return 0;
}
```

for the number 149 it should return 1 
(only bit number 7 is turned on)

Comment: Before asking here for help, please always switch on all compiler warnings. For example, compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Os asdf.c`. Then fix the warnings, then come back. We will happily answer your remaining questions, or any questions you have about the warnings you see. But not these trivial ones that are already answered by your compiler.

Comment: Why do you expect `count_odd_bits(149)` to be 1? 149 is 10010101 in binary, and that means there are 4 bits set.

Comment: `... else
            x = x << 1;` I don't think you want an `else` here unless you want an infinite `while` loop once it finds a condition that's true on the `if`. Also you probably want `>>` not `<<`. Finally, the conditions `(x % 2 == 1)` and `(x & 1)` have the same truth value, so `(x % 2 == 1) && (x & 1)` is redundant.

Comment: Did you test 147 as well? That one also runs into an endless loop.

Comment: There is no conversion specifier `%ul`. You need **`%lu`** and you should *read the compiler diagnostics*

Comment: since it counts only the "1" bits at all of the odd number places, number 149 has only one turned on bit, in index [7]. also i work with all the warning in the compiler. since i got no warnings whatsoever, i turned to this platform for help.

Comment: The `scanf` function thinks the format specifer `%ul` is `%u` and then an `'l'` must be matched. If you try entering two values with `"%ul%ul"` you'll find only the first one gets accepted, to `unsigned int` and not to `unsigned long` so the result is UB. MSVC compiler missed that because it is a valid, if inappropriate, syntax.

Comment: One other note, not sure what you mean by "counting the odd bits". A 1 bit is always odd, and 0 is even, so do you mean just counting the 1 bits? Or do you mean only counting 1's that are at odd positions? Your code currently attempts to count *all* of the 1 bits (any position), not just at the odd positions. If you want at the odd positions, then you want `x = x >> 2` (skip the even bits) rather than `x = x >> 1` in your loop..

Comment: Per your comment *i work with all the warning in the compiler. since i got no warnings whatsoever*, if you set the warning options correctly, this should not be the case. What exactly did you enter to compile the program?

Comment: exactly what is written above (by you) @lurker ans also the warning: -pedantic.

Comment: I didn't write a command line, so I don't know what you're referring to. Maybe you don't understand my question. I'm not asking for the code, I'm asking for the command line where you told the compiler you wanted warnings on.

Answer (score 2):

In the function you don't change `x` when the `if` is true. So you'll end up in an endless loop.

```
int count_odd_bits(unsigned long int x) {

    int count = 0;
    while (x) {
        if ((x % 2 == 1) && (x & 1))
            count++;                     // x not changed --> endless loop!!
        else
            x = x << 1;

    }
    return count;
}
```

Further it seems you need `x = x >> 1;` instead of the current code.

Also you don't need both `x % 2 == 1` and `x & 1` as they are the same.

So the code to count the number of ones could be:

```
int count_odd_bits(unsigned long int x) {

    int count = 0;
    while (x) {
        if (x & 1) count++;
        x = x >> 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

If you only want to count  **odd** bit position do

```
int count_odd_bits(unsigned long int x) {

    int count = 0;
    x = x >> 1;     // get rid of bit zero
    while (x) {
        if (x & 1) count++;
        x = x >> 2;    // shift by 2 to get 1->3->5->....
    }
    return count;
}
```